# Database performance improvements for current setup. (mysql - marriaDB)

Tags: innodb, optimization, mariadb

I've currently got a pretty hefty database (for me anyway) with multiple tables exceeding 15 million rows. I'm trying to improve performance on the whole table lookup, I implemented memcached to cache the already parsed result, but the initial lookups are very slow. 20seconds + on a big query.

`` SELECT `something`, ROUND(SUM( ( `amount` / `something_of_value` ) * `column` ) WHERE ... (the where clause is huge based on many conditionals) ``

Current setup:

> A managed vps server
>
> InnoDB storage for big tables
>
> 10.0.36-MariaDB
>
> 18gb ram
>
> 8 x 2.40 GHz CPU.

we don't use query_cache because 25% of queries are write queries, and after some research if a write/update query is done - the cache is deleted. Is this a correct approach?

Whats the best way to improve the initial lookup without upgrading the hardware?
I probably left out a lot of important details, so if you need more info just ask.
If you can steer me in a good general direction that would be appreciated also. I know about query optimization, but we are trying to improve the time of lookup and generally mysql performance.

EDIT:

full query:

```
SELECT  `metric`, SUM( `amount` )
    FROM  big_table
    WHERE  1
      AND  (`metric` = '1' )
      AND  (`source` = 'some_unique_source'
              OR  `source` = 'some_other_unique_source'
              OR  `source` = 'yet_another_unique_source'
              OR  `source` = 'some_most_unique_source'
              OR  `source` = 'almost_last_unique_source'
              OR  `source` = 'the_last_unique_source' 
           )
      AND  (`platform` = '2'
              OR  `platform` = '1'
              OR  `platform` = '3' 
           )
      AND  (`account` = '1'
              OR  `account` = '2'
              OR  `account` = '3'
              OR  `account` = '4'
              OR  `account` = '5'
              OR  `account` = '6'
              OR  `account` = '7'
              OR  `account` = '8'
              OR  `account` = '9'
              OR  `account` = '10'
              OR  `account` = '11'
              OR  `account` = '12' 
           )
      AND  (`something_id` = 'some.unique.id' )
      AND  `target_date` >= '2018-08-27'
      AND  `target_date` <= '2018-08-27'
    GROUP BY  `metric`;
```

Create query:

```
CREATE TABLE `big_table` (
  `stat_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `metric` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `source` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `platform` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `account` int(2) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `something_id` varchar(128) DEFAULT 'EMPTY SOMETHING_ID',
  `target_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `version` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `amount` decimal(16,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000' ,
  `tax` decimal(12,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000' ,
  `currency` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency_rate` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT '500.000000',
  `rate_updated` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `multiplier` decimal(16,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.000000',
  `unique_key` varchar(180) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `caption` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `finalised` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stat_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_key` (`unique_key`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `target_date` (`target_date`,`currency`),
  KEY `index_country` (`country`),
  KEY `currency_rate` (`currency_rate`,`multiplier`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43453089 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

---

**Edit:**

The date is always 1 day - the script runs a foreach date based on user inputted date range. The returned mysql result is parsed into a multidimensional array and then parsed into a json file after the datarange finishes.
Now that I think about it,a better approach may be to make a more intelligent query where the result would be grouped by date, though I don't know how much of an improvement that would be regarding speed. There are 5 main tabs, each selecting a different [main] thing - either grouping and selecting accounts, metrics, sources, platforms, countries and something_id, then the where clauses are also constructed from user input and may be different.  This is a custom analytics dashboard if that helps understanding what we are using this for.

A lot of different selects can be chosen by the user and a custom query is constructed based on the user input. I've reduced the select size by excluding the countries because on default it loaded all > 250 countries as where clauses making the the query length pretty ridiculous and embarrassing. For clarification - countries are all marked as selected on default. Pasting it into the answer made me realise that it could be wastly improved. Removing countries if all are selected reduced the load time with parsing from 21 secs~ to 8-10secs (30day foreach loop with basically the select you see on a 14million database rows). Though if the user would exclude at least one country, the sql would be constructed with 250~ where countries. I'm thinking about making an algorithm where if there are only a few of unselected countries to make a where country <> 'unselected' instead of loading all the selected ones ultimately making the query less in size.

Comment: yes, not using query_cache for this case is a good idea. You could try other [optimizer_switch](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/optimizer-switch/) settings. Overall you need to improve the query and the tables. Can show the `EXPLAIN {query}` output and `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tblname}`? Do you think you have index the table(s) right? Have you used JOIN rather than LEFT JOIN whereever possible. For multiple conditions on a single table have you considered a [generated column with index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/)?

Comment: explain output ->
**id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra**

1
SIMPLE
table_name
range
target_date,index_country,metric
target_date
4
NULL
153856
Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort


I'm not using joins for this table at all, this query took 144seconds in the slow_query log

Comment: This is rather incomprehensible. Please edit it into the question and format it neatly and include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE {table}` information for table used. A full query would also help a lot.

Comment: added the create and explain queries.

Comment: Great start. Is it most common for this query to be on a small date range with respect to the size of the data? Is metric=1 always used? Your list of sources, is this always the list that is used?  Is the platform list always used? Is the account list always used? Do these sets of sources/platforms/accounts correspond to a logical grouping?

Comment: @danblack updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have 1 day, you have 2.  If you really wanted only one day and the column is a `DATE`, then simply say `target_date = '2018-08-27'`.  This will help in designing the optimal index.

Start with the `=` columns (in any order):

```
INDEX(something_id, metric, target_date,
      xxxx)   -- then add one other column in the WHERE
```

If there are only 3 "platforms", then *leave out the test for it*.  I assume you are dynamically building the query.  So put a little more effort into the UI to optimize things as you go.

Unfortunately, you may need multiple indexes to handle multiple use cases.  It is not reasonable to have more than, say, 10 indexes.  So design indexes that are likely to be used and start with the `=` columns.  Don't bother with indexes longer than, say, 4 column.

Other issues:

- `int(2)` -- INT always takes 4 bytes; see `TINYINT` (etc) for space-savings.
- `DEFAULT NULL` -- use `NOT NULL` when appropriate.
- Change the `OR`s to `IN`s.  This won't improve performance, but it will be cleaner.
- After moving to `IN`, you can say `country NOT IN (short-list)`.
- A Comment mentions `JOIN` vs `LEFT JOIN`, but I don't see either??

If the data is never modified after it is inserted, then building and maintaining [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) is the way to go.  Carefully designed, about 5 such tables could handle maybe 50 different queries.  And the queries against these would run perhaps 10 times as fast.  For more discussion, provide a list of the likely queries.

(I added some Comments about summary tables onto danblack's Answers.)

Variants:

- `foo LIKE '%something'` -- can't use `foo` part of index due to leading wildcard
- `foo <> 'blah'` or `foo NOT IN ('blah')` -- probably treated like a "range", therefore, `foo` may be harmful (to performance) if too early in index; may be helpful if last.
- `country NOT IN ('Foostan')` versus `country IN (very-long-list)` -- the very-long-list takes some time to parse, etc; so `NOT IN` will be slightly better.
- Elimination of "all options checked" -- Do it.  The Optimizer can't tell the difference between that and "some checked".  So, yes, it is a *potential* optimization.

Once you have done things like those, the next challenge will be to pick a limited set of 'composite' `INDEXes` -- perhaps 5 indexes with 3 columns each.  Keep track of the queries that users hit you with.  The slowlog is one way to do this.

Comment: `JOIN` comments was before there was a query posted. On space saving is non-UTF8 varchar columns where the dataset is only latin going to help?

Comment: @danblack - "abc" will take 4 bytes in a `VARCHAR(20)` column, regardless of the `CHARACTER SET` of that column.  (Well, except for utf16 and a few others.)  `CHAR(..)` may be a different matter.  Also temp tables may matter.  But nothing egregious in the current schema.

Comment: I altered the table information and query information before posting, this is causing some confusion, sorry for that. In reality the script is only creating one day date ranges. Some of the query variations include a `something_id` IS LIKE '%something%';
and a variations of selected accounts, metrics, platforms and sources. I think a big help for default load times will be query optimization by excluding where selects if all options are selected, and generating a <> 'something' if less options are unselected than selected.

Comment: @PaaPs - I responded to your Comment.

Answer (score 0):

As you are going to be grabbing 30 days you may as well use a `GROUP BY target_date` and put the `target_date` in the result fields, will save some query parsing overhead.

As the query is always going to iterate over the range of the `target_dates`, and this will likely be the best column for the start of the index. To save the query from going back to the table space to fetch each row to further filter the result, or as a result (i.e. the `amount`). An index should start with `date`, and include all fields of the where clause and the `amount`. As this ends up with a largish index recommend creating it separately to the existing `target_date` index.

To make this query is faster when the user say selects one country, assuming this is a common case, a index `country`, `target_date`, {other fields} will aid this form of query. Likewise if a single `metric`, `something_id` or other field is common as a *single* value selection (i.e `x=5`, but not `x=5 or x=9`).

Comment: so:

CREATE INDEX idx_date ON big_table (( `target_date` + `metric` + `source` + `platform` + `account` + `something_id` + `country` +`amount` ));

Seems about right?  Wouldn't this be overkill?

Comment: looks right. Overkill? well that depends on the query benefit gained. Obviously more indexes eventually slows inserts. The alternate is getting a form of summary table going grouped by target_date.

Comment: created the indexes, load time decreased but 1-2 seconds. Thank you

Comment: 1-2 seconds for 30 days worth?

Comment: yes. The time was reduced from 8 secs to around 6.

Comment: When you have multiple days, `target_date` should be _last_, not _first_.

Comment: An 8-column index may be possible, but it is rarely worth doing.

Comment: Typically, a Summary Table is grouped by a "few" columns, usually including a date.  A "good" summary table will have one-tenth as many rows as the original table.  And, hence, the final query will run 10 times as fast.

Comment: 8 sec down to 6 -- you should be able to do better; let's see the details.

Comment: I left `target_date` first because it seemed the rest of the query was potentially populated with multiple criteria. If a query hit a range criteria on another non-target_date index, then the traversal would be quite large, while the target_date range seems limited to 30 days. So I ensuring a maximum execution time of 6-8 seconds. Should of explained that more. Thanks for providing more details.

Comment: what details would you like to see? the query that was ran and the load time with the created indexes?

Comment: @danblack - If the only form is `target_date = 'constant'`, then it can be first.  But if it is ever like the OP shows it (a range), putting it first would stop the use of the the `INDEX`; then it needs to be _last_, and it is competing with all the `INs`.

Comment: @PaaPs - See my Comment above; turning a single day into `=` is very important.

Comment: When _building_ the summary table, it does not matter what you do with target_date; when _accessing_ the summary table `=` things in the `WHERE` need to come first in the `INDEX`.  `date = ...` would be happy with date first; `date BETWEEN ...` would not.  The size of the Summary table obviates any discussion of I/O due to jumping around.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2, based on the target_date data being generally static after creation you could create a summary table based on date.

```
CREATE TABLE `summary_of_big_table` (
  `target_date` date NOT NULL,
  `metric` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `source` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `platform` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `account` int(2) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `something_id` varchar(128) DEFAULT 'EMPTY SOMETHING_ID',
  `country` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `amount` decimal(16,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`target_date`),
  KEY `index_country` (`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Index with fields there's likely to be few single values of.

Populated will data group by all the parameters and amount totalled:

```
INSERT INTO summary_of_big_table AS
SELECT target_date, metric, source,
  platform, account, something_id, country,
  SUM(amount) as amount
FROM big_table
GROUP BY target_date, metric, source,
  platform, account, something_id, country
```

Comment: Again, add some indexes, starting with the columns likely to be tested with `=`.  Incrementally populate the summary table(s); don't rebuild from scratch.

Comment: I probably won't go trough the hassle of rebuilding the table and reimporting the data right now. But will keep in mind that this is a possibility. Thank you

Comment: @PaaPs - A Summary Table is an extra table, not a rebuild of the main table.  No "reimporting", however it does involve fetching all the data from the main table to _initialize_ the summary table.